# CSS Styles are not available on Firefox/IE

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I designed a website using Dreamviewer. The styles I applied to the webpage are not available on Firefox and IE, webpage is displayed in plain HTML format. But all styles are well displayed in Chrome.What is the reason for that and how can fix that problem?

This is my stylesheet

```
*       { padding:0; margin:0; border:0; }

p   {  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#202020; line-height:180%;}
h1, h2, h3, h4  { color:#00486A; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
h1  { padding: 5px 5px 10px 0; font-size:24px;}

#wrapper    { margin:5px auto; width:1000px; background-color:#E6E6FF;} /*opacity:0.8; filter:alpha(opacity=80)}*/
body        { background:url(../img/backgrounds/sparkling_design-HD.jpg); background-repeat:repeat; }
#logo       { float:left; margin:10px 5px 10px 20px; opacity:1; ;}
#logo img   { opacity:1;}


#loginform  { float:right; padding: 20px 30px 10px 10px; margin: 10px 10px; }
#loginform a    { float:right; clear:both; }
#loginform a:link       { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#666; text-decoration:none; }
#loginform a:visited    { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#666; text-decoration:none; }
#loginform a:active     { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#666; text-decoration:none; }
#loginform a:hover      { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#999; text-decoration:none; text-decoration:underline;}
#loginform a:focus      { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#666; text-decoration:none; }
#loginform label    { float:left; width:70px; line-height: 100%; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#666; font-size:12px; padding-top:5px;}
#loginform input    { -webkit-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px; width:150px; line-height:180%; height:20px; margin-bottom:10px; padding-right:5px; border:1px solid #999; padding-left: 8px;}
#loginform input[type=submit]   { float:right; text-align:center; width:75px; background-color:#82BDFF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#333333; padding-left:8px; border: 1px #999999 solid; line-height:10px;}
#loginform input[type=submit]:hover { background-color:#0060FF; color:#FFF; }

#topnav     { clear:both; padding:10px 5px 10px 5px; margin:5px 5px 5px 20px; border-top:1px #B7B1FE solid; border-bottom:1px #B7B1FE solid;}
#topnav ul li { display:inline; list-style-type:none; padding-left:20px; }
#topnav ul li a:link    { font-family:'Noto Serif',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; text-decoration:none; color:#00324A; font-weight:bold; }
#topnav ul li a:active  { font-family:'Noto Serif',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; text-decoration:none; color:#00324A; font-weight:bold; }
#topnav ul li a:visited { font-family:'Noto Serif',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; text-decoration:none; color:#00324A; font-weight:bold; }
#topnav ul li a:hover   { font-family:'Noto Serif',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; text-decoration:none; color:#7C96FC; font-weight:bold; }
#topnav ul li a:focus   { font-family:'Noto Serif',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; text-decoration:none; color:#00324A; font-weight:bold; }

#banner { clear:both; margin:5px 20px; width:960px;}
#banner img { padding: 10px 0 10px 15px; }

#content    { float:left; width:700px; padding:10px 20px 10px 10px; margin:5px 5px 10px 10px; text-align:justify;}
#rightpane  { float:right; width:220px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:180%; color:#202020; margin-right: 20px; background-color:#D9DDFF; margin-bottom:20px; border:1px #0080C0 solid; border-radius:5px;}

#searchbox  { padding:10px 5px 10px 20px; margin-top:5px; }
#search input[type=text]    { border-radius:5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px; height: 20px; width:150px; border:1px #0080C0 solid; margin-right: 5px; }
#search input[type=submit]  { border-radius:5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px; height:25px; width:30px; border:1px #0080C0 solid; background-color:#82BDFF; line-height:5px;}
#search input[type=submit]:hover    { background-color:#0060FF; color:#FFF; }
#searchbox h3   { margin-left:0; }

/*---------------------Signup page------------ */
#form-content   { border: 1px solid #666; float:left; width:690px; padding:10px 20px 10px 10px; margin:5px 15px 10px 20px; }
#form-add-account input[type=text], #form-add-account input[type=password]  { width: 200px; height:20px; border-radius:5px; border: 1px #0080C0 solid;}
#form-add-account label { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#666;}
#form-add-account table { padding-top: 5px; }
/*---------------------------------------------*/


#latest-posts   { padding:10px 5px 10px 10px; margin:20px 0; }
#latest-posts ul    { list-style-type:none; padding-right:5px; padding-left:10px; line-height: 180%;}
#latest-posts ul li a:link      {  text-decoration:none; color:#202020;}
#latest-posts ul li a:active    {  text-decoration:none; color:#202020;}
#latest-posts ul li a:visited   {  text-decoration:none; color:#202020;}
#latest-posts ul li a:hover     {  text-decoration:none; color:#7C96FC; text-decoration:blink;}
#latest-posts ul li a:focus     {  text-decoration:none; color:#202020;}

#recommendations    { padding:10px 5px 10px 10px; margin:20px 0; }
#recommendations ul { list-style-type:none; padding-right:5px; padding-left:10px;}
#recommendations ul li a:link       {  text-decoration:none; color:#202020;}
#recommendations ul li a:active {  text-decoration:none; color:#202020;}
#recommendations ul li a:visited    {  text-decoration:none; color:#202020;}
#recommendations ul li a:hover      {  text-decoration:none; color:#7C96FC; text-decoration:blink;}
#recommendations ul li a:focus      {  text-decoration:none; color:#202020;}

#footer     { clear:both; width:980px; margin:10px auto; border-top:2px #CCCCCC dotted; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#666;}
#footer p   { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#666; }
#footer h4  { font-size:11px; padding-bottom:4px; }

#social-media   { float:left; width:230px; margin:10px 0px 10px 30px;}
#social-media ul    {  list-style-type:none; line-height:180%;}
#social-media ul li a:link      {  text-decoration:none; color:#666;}
#social-media ul li a:active        {  text-decoration:none; color:#666;}
#social-media ul li a:visited   {  text-decoration:none; color:#666;}
#social-media ul li a:hover     {  text-decoration:none; color:#7C96FC; text-decoration:blink;}
#social-media ul li a:focus     {  text-decoration:none; color:#666;}

#contacts   { float:left;width:230px; margin:10px 0px 10px 120px; }
#notice     { width:230px; float:right; margin-top:10px; }
#footer-bottom      {  clear:both; text-align:center; padding:10px 10px 20px 10px; border-top:2px #CCCCCC dotted; }
```

Comment: Post your code, we can't debug something as ambiguous as this (also it's Dreamweaver)

Comment: ok.I edited the question.

Comment: Which bits of it aren't working?

Comment: Could you also post the HTML? Also, are these styles linked to in a .CSS file, or are they in the .HTML file?

Comment: These are included in a styles.css file and linked to the HTML file.

Comment: Check the Error Console in Firefox (CTRL+SHIFT+J), what does it say?

Comment: Please, be kind to post your html code too (I think only `<head>` will be enough). At first glance it seems to me a problem with how do you linked the style sheet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any advanced or complex CSS code, so all modern browsers should support it. Anyway, here is a checklist:

## Checklist

- Did you checked different browser versions (you can switch inside Internet Explorer between older versions)? Check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699485(v=vs.85).aspx
- Did you try a more simplified CSS?
- Did you clean up your browser cache?
- Did you try "Browser Sniffing"? Check: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_sniffing
- Did you try it on another computer?

If you testing online you might want to check your `.htaccess`.

Comment: Thank you @Julian. I tried it with firefox both in Ubuntu and Windows. But results were the same. No styles at all. I'll try your checklist. Thanks.